# No shadows on plane in Eevee Rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Cycle renders is all good.
[image]
but, here is the Eevee one.
[image]
Its someway apart. What settings I need to change?

Comment: What type of light are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the shadows stand out the most, a point light with a small radius is ideal. However, if you are using an area light or a sun light (or other large scene lighting), you can still achieve clean shadows by disabling "Soft Shadows" in the Render Properties settings. This will give the shadow an "aliased" look, however, so you may have to increase the Cube Size accordingly. Also, make sure to check "High Bitdepth".

[image: Shadow1]

For any lights you are using, go to the light properties, and make sure "Contact Shadows" is checked. This will make sure adjacent touching surfaces don't allow light to leak through.

[image: Shadow2]

Comment: Gotta admit, answers like this one are very appreciated :). Was never sure what these settings actually do.